Why can't we push into vector while accessing it?
class Solution {
public:
    void func(vector<int>& nums, vector<vector<int>>& ans, int target){
        if(target == -1){
            vector<int> v;
            ans.push_back(v);
            return;
        }
        func(nums, ans, target - 1);
        for(auto x : ans){
            x.push_back(nums[target]);
            ans.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        func(nums, ans, nums.size() - 1);
        return ans;
    }
};

In func() function I get an error while pushing vector<int> x in vector<vector<int>> ans while accessing it.
What is the internal reason for this?

"...I get an error while pushing vector x in vector...". Ok, so what is the error message?

Why are you using competive coding to learn C++?, that will not work. Read this documentation on std::vector and pay attention to iterator invalidation. In other words you can NOT change the content of the vector while iterating over it.

You really should be learning C++ first, e.g. have a look at learncpp.com, get familiar with the cppreference and finally read the C++ core guidelines to see how current C++ is to be used.

Suppose this was allowed. You are iterating over a vector, but during that iteration you add some items to the vector, some at the beginning, some at the end, some in the middle, you also remove some items from the vector including maybe the item you are currently examining. Now the iteration continues, but where does it continue? Does the iteration have to now include the items you added at the beginning, or just at the end? What about the items you added in the middle? What about the items you have deleted? Some will have already been iterated over, but some will not, is that a problem?

If you want this to be allowed then you have to define the precise conditions under which it is allowed, and also the precise behaviour when the container is modified. And don't forget that you have to consider all containers, not just vectors, but anything you can use a ranged based for loop on. And don't forget that this includes user defined containers. I'm sure this can be done, and if you can work out all the details you could put together a proposal for the C++ standards committee.

Competitive coding to learn C++ is like solving sudoku puzzles to learn math.

What I'm actually saying is that this is a lot more complex than you have considered, and the standards committee, quite reasonably picked the simple option and said that you are not allowed to modify the container being iterated over.

"push into vector while accessing it" -- It's logically impossible to push into a vector without accessing it (because pushing is a form of access). I think you mean "while iterating over it"?

Your for (auto x : ans) assumes that iterators of ans will not be invalidated within the body of the loop.    ans.push_back(x) invalidates iterators of ans, since it resizes ans and (potentially) increases its capacity.     In terms of "internal" machinery, this is because the begin() and end() iterators of ans are obtained before the first iteration, and used to control the loop (so invalidating anss iterators within the loop breaks how the loop is controlled).

push_back potentially changes the capacity of the vector and with that, iterators, like those used internally in your range-based for loop, gets invalidated. Note that the end() iterator gets invalidated even if the capacity of the vector doesn't need to be increased:
cppreference:

If after the operation the new size() is greater than old capacity() a reallocation takes place, in which case all iterators (including the end() iterator) and all references to the elements are invalidated. Otherwise only the end() iterator is invalidated.

I'm not sure what your algorithm is supposed to do, but in order to not use invalid iterators, this should do:
Replace:
for(auto x : ans) {

With:
// To make it a little more effective, but it's not needed to make it work:
//ans.reserve(ans.size() * 2); // since the loop will double the size of ans
for (size_t idx = 0, size = ans.size(); idx < size; ++idx) {
    auto x = ans[idx];

Here, the index is used instead, which will remain valid even after a reallocation has taken place.
